# Capture the floor texture with ARCore

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, graphics, arcore

I'm trying to capture the "floor texture" based on a ARCore detected plane and the environment (camera) texture. Then reapply this floor texture in a plane mesh, creating a digital floor based on reality.
I've uploaded an image to illustrate this:

[image: Illustration]

This is not a ARCore specific question, I think it can be resolved with math and graphics programming, maybe something like unprojecting the plane based on the camera matrix, but I do not know exactly how to do that.

Can someone help me?
Thanks!!

Comment: What does the system give you? The coordinates of the plane and a view/projection matrix?

Comment: @NicoSchertler yes, I have these data and also can capture the current image from camera.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, we have three important coordinate systems in this problem:

[image: Coordinate Systems]

We have the usual 3D world coordinate system that can be defined arbitrarily. We have a 2D coordinate system for the plane. The origin of that coordinate system is in the plane's center (note that I use the term *plane* synonymous for *rectangle* for this purpose) and the coordinates range from -1 to +1. And finally, we have a 2D coordinate for the image. Actually, we have two for the image: An unsigned coordinate system (as shown in the figure) with the origin in the bottom left and coordinates ranging from 0 to 1, and a signed one with coordinates ranging from -1 to 1.

We know the four corners of our plane in world space and the 3x4 view/projection matrix `P` that allows us to project any point in world space to image space using homogeneous coordinates:

```
p_image,signed = P * p_world
```

If your projection matrix is 4x4, simply drop the third row (last-but 1) as we are not interested in image-space depth.

We do not really care about world space as this is somewhat arbitrary. Given a 2D point in plane space, we can transform it to world space using:

```
p_world = 1/4 (p0 + p1 + p2 + p3) + u * 1/2 * (p1 - p0) + v * 1/2 * (p3 - p0)
```

The first part is the plane's origin and the point differences in the second and third terms are the coordinate axes. We can represent this in matrix form as

```
/ x \   / p1_x - p0_x   p2_x - p0_x   1/4 (p0_x + p1_x + p2_x + p3_x) \   / u \
| y | = | p1_y - p0_y   p2_x - p0_x   1/4 (p0_y + p1_y + p2_y + p3_y) | * | v |
| z |   | p1_z - p0_z   p2_x - p0_x   1/4 (p0_z + p1_z + p2_z + p3_z) |   \ 1 /
\ 1 /   \      0             0                         1              /
```

Let us call this matrix `M`.

Now, we can go directly from plane space to image space with:

```
p_image,signed = P * M * p_plane
```

The matrix `P * M` is now a 3x3 matrix. It is the homography between your ground plane and the image plane.

So, what can we do with it? We can use it to draw the image in plane space. So, here is what we are going to do:

We will generate a render target that we will fill with a single draw call. This render target will then contain the texture of our plane. To draw this, we:

1. Upload the camera image to the GPU as a texture
2. Bind the render target
3. Draw a full-screen quad with corners `(-1, -1), (1, -1), (1, 1), (-1, 1)`
4. In the vertex shader, calculate texture coordinates in image space from plane space
5. In the pixel shader, sample the camera image at the interpolated texture coordinates

The interesting part is number 4. We almost know what we need to do. We already know how to go to signed image space. Now, we just need to go to unsigned image space. And this is a simple shift and scale:

```
                   / 1/2  0  1/2 \
p_image,unsigned = |  0  1/2 1/2 | * p_image,signed
                   \  0   0   1  /
```

If we call this matrix `S`, we can then calculate `S * P * M` to get a single 3x3 matrix `T`. This matrix can be used in the vertex shader to calculate the texture coordinates from the plane-space points that you pass in:

```
texCoords = p_image,unsigned = T * p_plane
```

It is important that you pass the entire 3D vector to the fragment shader and do the perspective divide only in the pixel shader to produce a correct perspective.